# How is the unitless number used in the Transform property calculated?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


.container {
  padding:5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size:20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height:200px;
}



.inside {
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  background: lightcoral;
  transform: scaleY(2) scaleX(1); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <p class="inside">This is a normal text.</p>
</div>
```

How is the unitless number calculated? Presumably it's relative to the font-size, but it's clearly not multiplied by it. For line-height, i know the number is multiplied with the font-size, but for transform property, that doesn't seem to be the case. So, how is it calculated!?

Comment: `transform: scaleY(x)` means: Enlarge `x` times in Y axis

Comment: Okay - where did you read this?

Comment: @Ihatecontrolfreaks [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleY#Syntax).

Comment: @user4642212 I read that several times. Where specifically does it say that scaleY(x) means enlarge x times in the axis? It just says that the number represents the scaling factor.

Comment: “scaling factor” _means_ “enlarge x times”. That’s what [scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_%28geometry%29) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transform: scaleY(x)` means: "Enlarge `x` times in the Y axis"

As an empirical reflection on this definition, you can examine the following code:

```js
function insertHeightAsContent(elementId) {
  const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  const height = element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  element.innerHTML = `My height is ${height}px`;
}

insertHeightAsContent('original');
insertHeightAsContent('scale1-5');
insertHeightAsContent('scale2');
insertHeightAsContent('scale3');
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: tomato;
}

#original { margin-top: 100px }
#scale1-5 { transform: scaleY(1.5) }
#scale2 { transform: scaleY(2) }
#scale3 { transform: scaleY(3) }
```

```html
<div id="original"></div>
<div id="scale1-5"></div>
<div id="scale2"></div>
<div id="scale3"></div>
```